# Remove cause from jooq stacktrace exception

Tags: java, jdbc, jooq

I'm trying to remove or hide sensitive data from Jooq exception handler, I've tried implementing a listener to handle the exception but I realized that the query with the sensitive data (Bind values for example) comes from a java.sql.BatchUpdateException which does not belong Jooq but java.sql.

So, my question is, how do you hide sensitive data on exceptions without losing the complete exception information?

This is an example:

```
    Caused by: org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [insert into "public"."table" ("id", "sensitvefield") values (?, ) on conflict ("id", "sensitvefield") do update set "id" = ?, "sensitvefield" = ? where ("public"."mytable"."id" = ? and "public"."mytable"."sensitvefield" = ?)]; Batch entry 0 insert into "public"."mytable" ("id","sensitvefield"]") values (2653933, sensitivefielddata) was aborted: ERROR: value too long for type character varying(50)  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.
    at org.jooq_3.14.15.POSTGRES.debug(Unknown Source)
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.translate(Tools.java:2903)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteContext.sqlException(DefaultExecuteContext.java:757)
    at org.jooq.impl.BatchSingle.executePrepared(BatchSingle.java:254)
    at org.jooq.impl.BatchSingle.execute(BatchSingle.java:170)
    at org.jooq.impl.BatchCRUD.executePrepared(BatchCRUD.java:148)
    at org.jooq.impl.BatchCRUD.execute(BatchCRUD.java:91)
    at com.myservice(ServiceRepository.kt:49)
    ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 insert into "public"."mytable" ("id", "sensitivefield",) values (2653933, sensitivefielddata) was aborted: ERROR: value too long for type character varying(50)  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.BatchResultHandler.handleError(BatchResultHandler.java:171)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2298)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:520)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.internalExecuteBatch(PgStatement.java:878)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeBatch(PgStatement.java:901)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeBatch(PgPreparedStatement.java:1644)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.executeBatch(ProxyStatement.java:127)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.jooq.tools.jdbc.DefaultStatement.executeBatch(DefaultStatement.java:112)
    at org.jooq.impl.BatchSingle.executePrepared(BatchSingle.java:234)
    ... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: value too long for type character varying(50)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2565)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2297)
    ... 53 common frames omitted
```

Here for example, if I replace all the causes, I will be losing the message ERROR: value too long for type character varying(50) which gives a lot of information, but, as you can see, there is sensitive information like sensitvefield and sensitivedata.

Does anyone know any workaround for it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the property `logServerErrorDetail` to prevent such leakages, see e.g.

- https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/pull/2148
- https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html#connection-parameters

The documentation reads:

> **logServerErrorDetail == boolean**
>
> Whether to include server error details in exceptions and log messages (for example inlined query parameters). Setting to false will only include minimal, not sensitive messages.
>
> By default this is set to true, server error details are propagated. This may include sensitive details such as query parameters.